# How I put a node.js swagger project into lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, swagger

I've been following a tutorial from [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/speed-up-your-restful-api-development-in-node-js-with-swagger) about creating a swagger API in node using [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md), and I've settled on using [swagger-express-mw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-express-mw). Everything looks straightforward, and pretty simple.

But I'm running into a stumbling block - how do I get my newly created API (or at least `hello_world`) onto AWS Lambda (which I was under the impression Swagger works really nicely with).

I have an AWS account set up, and I've played around with some routes - but I'm struggling to see where I put my code/what the workflow is.

Any information anyone has would be great. I've done a reasonable google, but I can't see anything straightforward.

Thanks all, and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're coming to AWS Lambda coming from Express, prepare yourself to *unlearn* it.

This should be the first thing you should read. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html

As for Swagger API integration, that would be AWS API Gateway's job. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html